# I'm having problems setting a foreingKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create the table "Prodotti" with 2 foreing keys to itself but I keep having this error: "The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ProdottiRichiesti' on type 'BugTracking_Entity.Prodotti' is not valid. The navigation property 'Prodotti' was not found on the dependent type 'BugTracking_Entity.Prodotti'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name."
This is my code:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Prodotti")]
     public  virtual int ProdottiRichiesti { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Prodotti")]
    public  virtual int ProdottiIncompatibili { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Standard")]
    public int StandardRefId { get; set; }
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

You have to create a Prodotti class instead of Standart like that example.

Comment: the properties are written into the "Prodotti" class

Comment: Db first class is also your database table. If you would like to create foreign keys you need more than one table that mean is you need two class for that case

Comment: the prodotti class code is the one I've written in the example, I'm not sure I may create a second class jsut to add a Foreign key